# Using different .inc files with same function names in .module file

Tags: 7, files

In our project, we have this module meant strictly for our custom API endpoints for our mobile applications to use. Currently, this is handled in a single .module file like so:

**my_project_mobile_api.module**

```
<?php

function my_project_mobile_api_menu() {
  return array(
    'api/v1/user/register' => array(
      'page callback' => 'account_register',
      'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in'
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    ),
    ...
  );
}

function account_register() {
  ... logic to create an account
}
```

Up until now, this has worked great for us, but now we need to add a V2 of the API. My idea was to extract all of the page callback functions (like `account_register`) into their own `.inc` file. This would look like this:

**my_project_mobile_api.module**

```
function my_project_mobile_api_menu() {
  return array(
    'api/v1/user/register' => array(
      'page callback' => 'account_register',
      'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in'
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    ),
    'api/v2/user/register' => array(
      'page callback' => 'account_register',
      'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in'
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    ),
    ...
  );
}
```

**my_project_mobile_api.v1.inc**

```
function account_register() {
  ... logic to create an account
}
```

**my_project_mobile_api.v2.inc**

```
function account_register() {
  ... logic to create an account (this logic differs from that of V1)
}
```

How can I make sure that my `.module` uses the right `account_register` function from the correct `.inc` file? Is there a way to specify the `file` in  the `api/v1/user/register` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file` key in your menu like:

I assume you have a **includes** directory contain both files `my_project_mobile_api.v1.inc` and `my_project_mobile_api.v2.inc` and both files contain `account_register` function.

Your `hook_menu` should be like the following.

```
function my_project_mobile_api_menu() {
  return [
    'api/v1/user/register' => [
      'page callback'   => 'account_register',
      'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
      'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'file'            => 'includes/my_project_mobile_api.v1.inc',
    ],
    'api/v2/user/register' => [
      'page callback'   => 'account_register',
      'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
      'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'file'            => 'includes/my_project_mobile_api.v2.inc',
    ],
  ];
}
```

You can also use `'file path'` if you files not in the same module take a look at this [example](https://api.drupal.org/comment/26443#comment-26443).